# Generate sequences of anniversary dates between 2 dates

Tags: r, date

I tried to generate a sequence of dates between two dates. By search all the old posts, I found very nice solution using `seq.Date`.

For example:

```
> seq.Date(as.Date("2016/1/15"), as.Date("2016/5/1"), by = "month")
[1] "2016-01-15" "2016-02-15" "2016-03-15" "2016-04-15"
```

The above function yields very nice solution. However, it doesnt work when the date is 30 or 31 in Jan.

```
> seq.Date(as.Date("2016/1/30"), as.Date("2016/5/1"), by = "month")
[1] "2016-01-30" "2016-03-01" "2016-03-30" "2016-04-30"
```

The second anniversary jumps to March instead of being capped at 29/Feb. I couldnt find a workaround for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that also works in other cases:

```
library(lubridate)
fun <- function(from, to, by) {
  mySeq <- seq.Date(as.Date(from), as.Date(to), by = by)
  as.Date(sapply(mySeq, function(d) d + 1 - which.max(day(d - 0:3))), origin = "1970-01-01")
}

fun("2016/1/30", "2016/5/1", "month")
# [1] "2016-01-30" "2016-02-29" "2016-03-30" "2016-04-30"
fun("2017/1/31", "2017/5/1", "month")
# [1] "2017-01-31" "2017-02-28" "2017-03-31" "2017-04-30"
fun("2017/1/29", "2017/5/1", "month")
# [1] "2017-01-29" "2017-02-28" "2017-03-29" "2017-04-29"
```

What `fun` does is that it subtracts `0:3` from each date and chooses the one that has the largest day.

Comment: Nice, but why does this require `lubridate`?

Comment: Hi, I modified the function to something like this: `fun <- function(from, to) {
    no.month <- length(seq.Date(as.Date(from), as.Date(to), by = '1 month'))
    as.Date(from) %m+% months(seq(1:no.month)-1)
}`

Comment: @thelatemail, for the `day` function.

Comment: @southwind, looks great!

Answer (score 0):

With lubridate package

```
library('lubridate')

pmin(
    ymd('2018-01-30') + months(0:11),  # NA where month goes over
    ymd('2018-01-01') + months(1:12) - days(1),  # last day of month
    na.rm = T
)

 [1] "2018-01-30" "2018-02-28" "2018-03-30"
 [4] "2018-04-30" "2018-05-30" "2018-06-30"
 [7] "2018-07-30" "2018-08-30" "2018-09-30"
[10] "2018-10-30" "2018-11-30" "2018-12-30"
```